# PHP array Reference Bug?

Tags: php, arrays, pass-by-reference, php-5.3

With PHP is it even Possible to Pass arrays by Reference ? or its a Bug Only for Me.

```
class MyStack{
    private $_storage = array();

    public function push(&$elem){//See I am Storing References. Not Copy
        $this->_storage[] = $elem;
    }
    public function pop(){
        return array_pop($this->_storage);
    }
    public function top(){
        return $this->_storage[count($this->_storage)-1];
    }
    public function length(){
        return count($this->_storage);
    }
    public function isEmpty(){
        return ($this->length() == 0);
    }
}
?>
<?php
$stack = new MyStack;
$c = array(0, 1);
$stack->push($c);
$t = $stack->top();
$t[] = 2;
echo count($stack->top());
?>
```

Expected Result:`3`
But The Output is: `2`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you probably want is this:

```
class MyStack{
    /* ... */

    /* Store a non-reference */
    public function push($elem) {
        $this->_storage[] = $elem;
    }

    /* return a reference */
    public function &top(){
        return $this->_storage[count($this->_storage)-1];
    }

    /* ...*/
}

/* You must also ask for a reference when calling */
/* ... */
$t = &$stack->top();
$t[] = 2;
```

Comment: > You don't need to "Ask for a reference when calling"

I thought Its true for Objects Only.
Ya It works But Why I need another `&` If the Function returns a reference ? meaningless
and Why `&$this->_storage[count($this->_storage)-1]` Crashes ?

Comment: @user Because `=` is the assignment operator, which doesn't do assignment by reference. If you do `$a = 1; $b =& $a; $c = $b`, `$c` won't be a reference either. That's just the way it is; if you want to assign by reference, you have to use `=&`. And what do you mean "crashes"? There's a segfault?

Comment: @user Can you post a small script that reproduces the problem and post it somewhere (e.g. pastebin)?